# Derive complexity from recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

On the Wikipedia article on Karatsuba algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Time_complexity_analysis) it is stated:

$T(n) = 3 T(\frac{n}{2}) + cn + d$

And then, by invocation of the "master theorem" it is deduced that $T(n) = O(n^{\log_2{3}})$.

My question is, is there an easy way in this case to derive this complexity from the relation without referring to the master theorem nor to a recurrence that supposes we already know the result?

Comment: Master theorem is the easy way for standard recurrences. If that doesn't fit well, you may do substitution to get the exact results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve the recurrence without using the Master theorem and without substitution (which requires guessing the form of the solution). I'll assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of $2$ and that $T(1) \le c + d$ (otherwise you can just consider a larger value of $d$).

Let's make some simplifications first. They are not really needed, but will make the following calculations easier.  First of all notice that you can hide the additive constant $d$ into the multiplicative constant of $n$. For example, by defining $k=(c+d)$ you have $T(n) \le \frac{3}{2} T(n/2) + kn$ for all $n \ge 1$.

We can now get rid of $k$ altogether by defining $S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{k}$, which satisfies $S(n) = \Theta(T(n))$ and leads to the following recurrence:
$$
S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{k} \le 3 \cdot \frac{T(n/2)}{k} + n = 3  S(n/2) + n.
$$

Consider now the recursion tree for $S(n)$. Each recursive call will halve the input size, therefore the height of the tree will be $\log_2 n$. Moreover, there are  $3^i$ recursive calls  at a generic depth $i$ (each having  input size $\frac{n}{2^i}$), which contribute $3^i \cdot \frac{n}{2^i} = n \cdot \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^i$ to $S(n)$.

Upper bounding $S(n)$, and hence $T(n)$, is now just a matter of finding an upper bound to the overall time spent across all depths, which yields the following geometric series (the base of all $\log$s is $2$):
$$
\begin{align*}
S(n) \le 
n \sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^i &
\le n \cdot \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{\log n + 1} 
= \frac{3n}{2} \cdot 2^{\log n \cdot \log \frac{3}{2}}
= \frac{3n}{2} \cdot n^{\log \frac{3}{2}} \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \cdot n^{\log 2 + \log \frac{3}{2}}
=  \frac{3}{2} n^{\log 3} = O(n^{\log 3}).
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $n=2^m$. The recurrence now writes

$$T(2^m)=3T(2^{m-1})+2^mc+d$$ or

$$S(m)=3S(m-1)+2^mc+d.$$

A solution of the homogeneous recurrence ($S(m)=3S(m-1)$) is $S(m)=3^m$ and this makes us set, by variation of the constant

$$S(m)=3^mR(m),$$ giving

$$R(m)=R(m-1)+\frac{2^mc+d}{3^m}.$$

The solution is easily seen to be

$$R(m)=R(0)+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^kc+d}{3^k}\\=R(0)+\frac{\dfrac23\left(1-\left(\dfrac23\right)^m\right)c+\dfrac13\left(1-\left(\dfrac13\right)^m\right)d}{1-\dfrac13}.$$

This is asymptotic to the constant

$$R(0)+c+\frac d2,$$

making $R(m)=\Theta(1)$, $S(m)=\Theta(3^m)$ and $T(n)=\Theta(3^{\log_2n})=\Theta(n^{\log_23})$.